# Django store prefetch_related result

Tags: django, prefetch

I know I can specify to store results of prefetch_related like this.

```
 my_objs = MyClass.objects.prefetch_related(
     Prefetch('relation', to_attr='relation_as_list')
 )

 for my_obj in my_objs:
     l = my_obj.relation_as_list
```

Is it the same thing as the following? 
Doc says prefetch_related stores result in Queryset, and I don't get where I'm getting a performance boost?

```
 my_objs = MyClass.objects.prefetch_related('relation')

 for my_obj in my_objs:
     l = list(my_obj.relation.all())  # looks like DB hit but it isnt?
```

Answer (score 8):

These two are same

```
MyClass.objects.prefetch_related('relation')

MyClass.objects.prefetch_related(
   Prefetch('relation', to_attr='relation_as_list')
)
```

> You can use the Prefetch object to further control the prefetch operation ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related))

You need a `Prefetch` object only when you need to refine the results of `prefetch_related`. For example you might not need every `relation` but specific ones, so you can refine the prefetch query.

> Using to_attr is recommended when filtering down the prefetch result as it is less ambiguous than storing a filtered result in the related manager’s cache ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related))

`to_attr` doesn't give additional performance boosts, it allows making `Prefetch` relations less ambiguous, as well as makes it possible to prefetch same relation with different QuerySets.

```
MyClass.objects.prefetch_related(
   Prefetch('same_relation', queryset=queryset_one, to_attr='relation_set_one')
   Prefetch('same_relation', queryset=queryset_two, to_attr='relation_set_two')
)
```

If you prefetch same relation with different `Prefetch` objects, there will be an additional query for each of them. Resulting prefetch QuerySets will be stored in a list, but the results are not lists like you assumed as `relation_as_list`. They are QuerySets. In your example, accessing both relations can be done with `all()`, like `my_obj.relation_as_list.all()` and `my_obj.relation.all()`

**About the performance boost**

In summary, `prefetch_related` gets the related objects in one (additional) DB hit which is where the performance boost comes from. `Prefetch` objects lets you further refine this DB call.

```
for item in yourmodel.object.all():
    for a_relation in item.relation.all():
        do_something(a_relation)  
        # WITHOUT PREFETCH RELATED YOU'D HIT DB EVERY TIME!! 
        # IMAGINE IF YOU HAD TONS OF ITEMS

# THIS WILL HAVE 2 DB HITS
for item in yourmodel.object.prefetch_related('relation').all().:
    for a_relation in item.relation.all():
        do_something(a_relation)
```